# MYsQL Grouping Count Query

Tags: mysql

Anybody please help me.

I have a query that needs to extract data that must show details of a certain model on a process.

Here is my query.

```
    select
x.Sequence as 'Sequence',
x.Process as 'Process',
x.pdt as 'Production Date',
x.mdl as 'Model',
count(x.bigbook) as 'Bigbook Count',
x.sb as 'Smallbook'
from
(
select distinct
'1' as 'Sequence',
'Cutting' as 'Process',
cut_pdt as 'PDT',
cut_shf as 'Shift',
cut_mdl as 'Mdl',
cut_bbn as 'Bigbook',
 count(cut_sbn) as 'SB'
from sum_cut_001 group by cut_bbn) x
group by x.mdl
```

That Result that it shows is like this.

```
---------|---------|-----------------|-------|----------------|------------------|
Sequence | Process | Production Date | Model | Big book Count | Small Book Count |
---------|---------|-----------------|-------|----------------|------------------|
1        | Cutting |    2012-01-30   |  GSX1 |     3          |        12        |
```

Each Model has 1 Bigbook and each Bigbook has 18 smallbook

So if i have 3 bigbooks for model GSX1 the output should be.

```
---------|---------|-----------------|-------|----------------|------------------|
Sequence | Process | Production Date | Model | Big book Count | Small Book Count |
---------|---------|-----------------|-------|----------------|------------------|
1        | Cutting |    2012-01-30   |  GSX1 |     3          |        54        |
```

Please Help me on how to query it correctly.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you have all your data in one table? It looks like it should be normalized.